# How to retrieve data from database and able to edit in summernote editor?

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, summernote

I'm facing a problem and i couldn't find a solution to solve it.
My problem is that i have apply a plugin which called as ( Wysiwyg - summernote editor into my Laravel framework project ) . Everything works fine but when i click on the edit page, the data is unable to retrieve from the database and directly edit with the editor function. Can anyone familiar with this help me out ? Thank you so much

[image: As you can see my placeholder is the value retrieve from the database, i just wondering why i couldn't put the data into the editor function and directly edit from it]

```
<div class="form-group">


 <label for="company_policy_policy_details">Please Enter Policy Details<span<p><font color="#F05340"> *</font></p></label></span>

                <input type="text" name="policy_details" id="abc"  class="form-control" value="{!!$policy->policy_details!!}" cols="139" rows="10">
                </textarea>
            </div>



            <div id="summernote"></div>

            <script>

                $('#abc').summernote({
                    placeholder:value="{!!$policy->policy_details!!}",
                    tabsize: 2,
                    height: 100
                });
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
            </div>`
```

Expected output = i want the value in placeholder are able to show inside the editor and able to edit it directly , Thankssssss

[image: After update , but not the expected output i want]

Comment: ` <input type="text" name="policy_details" id="abc"  class="form-control" value="{!!$policy->policy_details!!}" cols="139" rows="10">
                </textarea>` what is used for ? summernote does not need this

Comment: @AndySong this is for the column which i edit the data and store back into the database columns

Comment: input does not match textarea though

Comment: @AndySong i have uploaded a picture after updating , have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this code will show the data from your db.

```js
$('#summernote').summernote({
    placeholder: "{!!$policy->policy_details!!}",
    tabsize: 2,
    height: 100
}).summernote('code', `{!!$policy->policy_details!!}`);
```

Comment: ya it will show the value data from database , but the summernote editor is gone when i retrieve the value out from db

Comment: This is literally no different from my answer?

Comment: @James, sorry I did not see your answer, and I think the key part was that `id` is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write html code and add it to editor you can use **pasteHTML** , to Paste **HTML** string.

### pasteHTML

```
// @param {String} HTML string
var HTMLstring = '<div><p>Hello, world</p><p>Summernote can insert HTML string</p></div>';
$('#summernote').summernote('pasteHTML', HTMLstring)
```

### Code

If you want to get data from database use the below code :

```
$('#summernote').summernote('code', {{$data->content}});
```